# Non-Latin tags are not parsed as tags in SEDE

Tags: bug, tags, data-explorer, localization

For instance, in [this SEDE request](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/808845/questions-with-empty-revision-history) the cells in the tag column contain not parsed tags if at least one question's tag is not Latin only:

> [image: non clickable tags]

Comment: ...and that's why you shouldn't detect alphanumeric characters with `[a-z0-9]`.