# Data Explorer fails to properly format lists of tags with Cyrillic characters

Tags: bug, tags, data-explorer, localization

There is a minor issue with how Data Explorer handles tag output. Ordinarily it replaces every one of them with a decorated and clickable link.

But it seems like whenever that list includes tags with Cyrillic characters, commonly seen e. g. [on  "Stack Overflow in Russian"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags), it leaves the whole list as plain text.

Here is [a query that showcases the issue](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1077418/deleted-users-answers-link-question-title-tags-score?UserName=user181100) and a screenshot of the results it outputs right now:

[image: screenshot of the problem]

---

This would appear to be the wrong regexp that matches those: `/^(?:<[a-z0-9#.+-]+>)+$/`

Comment: related: [Auto-linkification of Tags.TagName fails when the tag name contains nonstandard characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226703/auto-linkification-of-tags-tagname-fails-when-the-tag-name-contains-nonstandard) and [Non-Latin tags are not parsed as tags in SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307231/non-latin-tags-are-not-parsed-as-tags-in-sede) and this is in the same regex area: [SEDE doesn't render links with non-standard characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242364/sede-doesnt-render-links-with-non-standard-characters)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ voted to close as a dup. But the issue is not resolved from what I understand, right?

Comment: @AntonMenshov this is a way how dups work. BTW I have [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307231/339911) about same issue too.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ yeah, I know. That's why I voted how I voted from the review queue. I was just wondering about the subject matter to confirm my quick read.

Comment: I've removed the status-review tag from this post because it's been closed as a duplicate of another question.